# How do I restart Kerberos

Tags: activity-monitor, restart, kerberos, smart-card

What OS process can I kill or force quit to terminate Kerberos?  It's gotten into some bad state where choosing `Sign in` only brings up an empty white box (missing the normal prompts inside).

I use Kerberos with a SmartCard on a regular basis.  My IT coordinator informed me that my PIV certificate was expiring soon.  To check the exact date, I did a `Sign out`, and then clicked `Sign in` - so far, so good - in the expected pop-up window, I clicked my certificate and clicked `inspect`, finding that it's end date is not til the end of October.

But after the certificate inspection and closing that window, I can't login to Kerberos; I just get the blank pop-up window.  I don't see a clear way to restart the process, either from the icon dropdown on the menu bar, or from Activity Monitor (I can restart my Mac, just prefer not to).  It must be a running process, but none of the names jump out at me as being for kerberos.  I'm running Ventura 13.5.

Comment: Try opening a new shell and running: `app-sso -r` then retry the card authentication.